# How to open a database file with no file type in SSMS?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms

I have a database file with no file type, I need to open it in SSMS first. When I try to open it, it says no editor for it. I tried to open it in a text editor by changing its name with a txt extension, it displayed unreadable code on the whole page. I have searched online it seems the only way is to change the file name with an extension. Is there any way to make SSMS recognize the generic extension file? Thanks

Larnu corrected me to use "Restore" instead of "Open". Thanks

New to database, need to learn everything.

Comment: You don't (in SQL Server at least) "open" a backup file, you `RESTORE` it. It's not a user readable file. Backup files are also propriety; you can't take a SQL Server backup and restore it on a MySQL instance or vice versa. if you need to migrate from one RDBMS to another, you'll need to script out the objects and data, while translating the syntax from one dialect to the other.

Comment: Funny how you ask how to OPEN a file within file type, and then hide "need t o convert it from MSSQL to MySQL" in the text. THAT is your issue, not opening it. The answer to open it is trivial in the workaround: RENAME THE FILE. Done, now it has an extension. But why in the world do you even assume SSMS would be able to CONVERT TO MYSQL? And what is the file? A database part (db's MSSQL have 2 files minimum) or a backup? Seriously, you bark up a tree that makes no sense and is impossible - a MsSql backup is that, there is no conversion.

Comment: Thanks Larnu and TomTom. Yes, migration can not be done in SSMS. I just want to explain the reason I want SSMS to restore the file. It's misleading the question. Correct it now. Now I know the keyword "Restore". Thanks Larnu